# How can I select all anchor tag whose href starting with tel: ie href="tel:12334......"

Tags: anchor

some text

some text 1-800-223-7440 or for all other inquiries please feel free to 
1-800-413-8840

How can I select all anchor tag whose href starting with tel: ie href="tel:+123-34......"

Comment: Select _in what language_ …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select them by using what? 
If you are using jQuery - you can write something like this: `jQuery('a[href^="tel"]')`